# Vuejs2 watch not working for data coming from ajax call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue2 application with a `watch` that doesn't fire when data coming from an ajax call.

### Html

```
<tr v-for="arrayresult , key in arrayresults">
    <td><input class='quantity' name='items_quantity_quantity[]' type='number'  value='1' @keyup='check_item_offer(arrayresult.id,arrayresult.unit_id,arrayresult.qty,key,arrayresult.item_tax_value)' @change='check_item_offer(arrayresult.id,arrayresult.unit_id,arrayresult.qty,key,arrayresult.item_tax_value)' @keyup.enter='go_to_message' v-model='arrayresult.qty'/></td>
</tr>
```

### Vue Code

```
watch:{
    // arrayresult come from the ajax call.
    'arrayresult.qty': {
        handler: function (after, before) 
        {
            alert("asdf");

        },
        deep: true
    }
}
```

Changing the `arrayresult.qty` with another prop everythings works

Comment: It sounds like a reactivity problem but we'd need to see the code responsible for getting this data into the component. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats or https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats may give you a hint about the possible cause.

Comment: The problem is most likely to be that the proxy is on arrayresult and not on a property of arrayresult. You need to either watch for the whole arrayresult changes or set quantity property in data and match it with indexes => arrayresult[ idx ] and quantity[ idx ]